# Import Variable from root __init__.py in a Python Package

Tags: python, package, python-import

I have an `__init__.py` file and I declared the following in my package.

The code is as follows:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from . import web
IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS = False
```

The structure of my project contains many sub-level packages like the one mentioned above called `web`.  Here is the basic structure:

```
dynamical (root package)
   -> __init__.py
   -> web
      -> __init__.py
      -> _func.py
```

For ease of use for user, I wanted the project level constants like `IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS` to be exposed to individuals can setup the scripts to work against an insecure site for testing there code.

I am having issues importing the variable `IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS` to `_func.py`.

Since it is at the root of the package, how do I import this?

```
from .. import IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS
```

seems to fail.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add your root package folder to the `sys.path` using `sys.path.append()`.

So in your `_func.py` file you can use this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    from os import sys, path
    pth = path.dirname(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))
    sys.path.append(pth)  # pth is your 'dynamical' folder
    from dynamical import IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS
```

Hope this helps!